# Fancy 3D Code Renderer

Tags: images, automation, code

I'm looking for an automated tool that takes a file or series of files and creates an image from small sections of the code.  Does something like this exist?

[image]
[image]

Comment: [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) jumps to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best results without installing any software you'd get using [Instacode](http://instacod.es/). As this is a web service you have to be comfortable with releasing that snippet to the public. Here some samples:
[image: sample1] [image: sample2] [image: sample3]

As already given in the comments you can script [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) and [Blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Manual/Extensions/Python) using Python. Thus it should be easy to extract some lines of code and use them as rendering input.

If you're familiar with POV-Ray, that might be also an option. [Text object in POVRay](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/65/).

While POV-Ray and Blender give you most flexibility in tweaking the look at the cost of work/time. Instacode gives you shiny results, well, *instantly*.

Comment: The url of the POV-Ray example is plain text, as noobs aren't allowed to insert more than 2 links per post...

Comment: Now the POV-Ray example is linked as well :-).

Comment: Just for the records, please use newcomer or, if it has to be shortened, newb...noob is mostly negatively used. ;)